# Avoid re-building model functionality in a Strapi custom controller

Tags: strapi

Using Strapi (v3), how can you maintain standard Strapi model features when using a custom controller and raw query?

The [Strapi docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#queries) mention that when implementing a custom controller, you will lose model functionality. Given this, is there still a way to manually leverage the model features, to avoid having to re-build everything from scratch?

For example:

A model with many fields (e.g. 40), with some fields being a relationship to other models (each having many fields).

Strapi generates everything for you: API, routes, filtering, etc. This is the power of Strapi!

Sample requests:

**Shows all**

```
/myModel
```

**Some basic filters**

```
/myModel?Cost_gte=1&Cost_lte=50
```

**Or filters dynamically generated (using `qs`)**

```
/myModel?_where[_or][0][0][stars]=2&_where[_or][0][1][pricing_lt]=80&_where[_or][1][0][stars]=1&_where[_or][1][1][categories.name]=French
```

Ultimately, after processing, these requests simply become SQL queries (from the perspective of the database).

**PROBLEM:**
For special contexts, I need to introduce some raw SQL into the queries above. The recommended way to do this is making a custom controller and manually formulating a query using BookshelfJS and Knex (tech that Strapi uses).

However this means having to interpret and process all of the request parameters myself; essentially building an entire controller from scratch.

**For example, a custom controller may look like:**

```
find: async (ctx) => {
       
    const knex = strapi.connections.default;
    var query = knex('myModel')
        .join('locations', 'myModel.Location', 'locations.id')

        // A whole ton of select statements
        .select('myModel.Cost as Cost')
        // ... and 50 more lines, maybe...

        // A whole ton of statements to process request parameters
        if(ctx.query.Cost_gte) query.where('events.Cost', '>=', ctx.query.Cost_gte)
        if(ctx.query.Cost_lte) query.where('events.Cost', '<=', ctx.query.Cost_lte)
        // ... and 50 more lines, maybe...

        // Here is where I use a raw query, performing distance calculation using db functionality
        if(ctx.query.Longitude && ctx.query.Latitude) {
            query.where(knex.raw(
                round(st_distance_sphere(
                st_geomfromtext(CONCAT('  POINT(',locations.Longitude, ' ', locations.Latitude,')'  )),
                st_geomfromtext(CONCAT('  POINT(` + ctx.query.Longitude + ` ` + ctx.query.Latitude + `) '))
                )) <= 5000`
            ))
        }

        const result = await query

        return result
      }
```

How can one avoid re-building everything from scratch?

Ultimately, I'm just looking to get search results within 50km of a user. All signs point towards doing a custom query being the only way.

Comment: got same issue, did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: No; I've basically built a manual controller. It will get way bigger in the future, so I'm looking for any efficiency. Other than this I'm using Strapi dashboard for everything else (other models) and it's great. Before Strapi I was doing everything manual anyways, lol, so it's still a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, not a solution but i went down the route of trying to replicate the strapi model filtering with some customisations that i needed.

leaving this here incase someone needs to do the same, ***warning*** it's probably missing stuff

```
        const result = await strapi
        .query('articles')
        .model.query(qb => {
            // try do the strapi filter
            var filters = ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'lte', 'gte', 'in', 'nin', 'contains', 'ncontains', 'consatinss', 'ncontainss', 'null']
            for(const param in ctx.query) {
                var array = param.split('.')
                var column = array.pop()
                var table = array.join('.').length > 0 ? array.join('.') : 'articles'
                var filter = column.match(/[^_]*$/)[0];
                if(filter!=column) column = column.slice(0, column.lastIndexOf('_'));
                if(filter==column) filter = 'eq';

                // join relations if needed
                switch (table) {
                    case 'guided_series':
                        qb.leftJoin('articles__guided_series', 'articles__guided_series.article_id', 'articles.id')
                        qb.leftJoin('guided_series', 'guided-sery_id', 'guided_series.id')
                        break;
                    case 'contributors':
                        qb.leftJoin('articles__contributors', 'articles__contributors.article_id', 'articles.id')
                        qb.leftJoin('contributors', 'contributor_id', 'contributors.id')
                        break;
                    case 'tags':
                        qb.leftJoin('articles__tags', 'articles__tags.article_id', 'articles.id')
                        qb.leftJoin('tags', 'tag_id', 'tags.id')
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                if(filters.includes(filter)) {
                    // fix bool values
                    ctx.query[param] = ctx.query[param] === "true" ? true : ctx.query[param];
                    ctx.query[param] = ctx.query[param] === "false" ? false : ctx.query[param];

                    switch (filter) {
                        case 'eq':
                            qb.where(`${table}.${column}`, ctx.query[param])
                            break;
                        case 'ne':
                            qb.where(`${table}.${column}`, '!=', ctx.query[param])
                            break;
                        case 'lt':
                            qb.where(`${table}.${column}`, '<', ctx.query[param])
                            break;
                        case 'gt':
                            qb.where(`${table}.${column}`, '>', ctx.query[param])
                            break;
                        case 'lte':
                            qb.where(`${table}.${column}`, '<=', ctx.query[param])
                            break;
                        case 'gte':
                            qb.where(`${table}.${column}`, '>=', ctx.query[param])
                            break;
                        case 'in':
                            if(Array.isArray(ctx.query[param])) {
                                // for extra flexibility, handle null here
                                if(ctx.query[param].includes('null')) {
                                    qb.where(`${table}.${column}`, 'in', ctx.query[param])
                                        .orWhereNull(`${table}.${column}`);
                                } else {
                                    qb.where(`${table}.${column}`, 'in', ctx.query[param])
                                }
                            } else {
                                qb.where(`${table}.${column}`, ctx.query[param])
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'nin':
                            if(Array.isArray(ctx.query[param])) {
                                qb.where(`${table}.${column}`, 'nin', ctx.query[param])
                                    .orWhereNull(`${table}.${column}`);
                            } else {
                                qb.where(`${table}.${column}`, '!=', ctx.query[param])
                                    .orWhereNull(`${table}.${column}`);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'contains':
                            //todo
                            break;
                        case 'ncontains':
                            //todo
                            break;
                        case 'containss':
                            //todo
                            break;
                        case 'ncontainss':
                            //todo
                            break;
                        case 'null':
                            if(ctx.query[param]) {
                                qb.whereNull(`${table}.${column}`)
                            } else {
                                qb.whereNotNull(`${table}.${column}`)
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // todo handle where, where[or]

            // default to 'en' locale
            qb.where('articles.locale', ctx.query._locale ?? 'en')

            // default to '10' limit
            qb.limit(ctx.query._limit ?? 10)

            // sorting
            if(ctx.query._sort) {
                var sorts = ctx.query._sort.split(',');
                sorts.forEach(element => {
                    var bits = element .split(':');
                    qb.orderBy(`articles.${bits[0]}`, bits[1])
                });
            } else {
                qb.orderBy('articles.published_at', 'DESC')
                qb.orderBy('articles.created_at', 'DESC')
            }
        })
        .fetchAll({
            withRelated: [
                'category', 'tags', 'contributors', 'localizations', {
                'guided_series': function(qb) {
                    //qb.where('slug', 'depression');
                }
            }]
        });

        const fields = result.toJSON();

        return fields;
```